# Creating a Deployment and PersistentVolumeClaim with dynamic AWS EBS backed claims

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, aws-ebs

I create a Deployment with a volumeMount that references a PersistentVolumeClaim along with a memory request on a cluster with nodes in 3 difference AZs us-west-2a, us-west-2b, and us-west-2c.

The Deployment takes a while to start while the PersistentVolume is being dynamically created but they both eventually start up.

The problem I am running into is that the PersistentVolume is made in us-west-2c and the only node the pod can run on is already over allocated.

Is there a way for me  to create the Deployment and claim such that the claim is not made in a region where no pod can start up?

Comment: My workaround for now is to add a taint to the node that is over allocated and that seems to ensure the claim and deployment don't end up on the over alllocated machine.
```
kubectl taint nodes node1 key=value:NoSchedule
```

Comment: Mevermind I was just getting lucky, it created the volume on us-west-2c again and my ec2 worker node on us-west-2c had the taint but not luck

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [Topology Awareness](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/dynamic-provisioning/#topology-awareness) feature.

> Topology Awareness
>
> In Multi-Zone clusters, Pods can be spread across
>   Zones in a Region. Single-Zone storage backends should be provisioned
>   in the Zones where Pods are scheduled. This can be accomplished by
>   setting the Volume Binding Mode.

Kubernetes released [topology-aware dynamic provisioning feature](https://kubernetes.io/blog/2018/10/11/topology-aware-volume-provisioning-in-kubernetes/) with kubernetes version 1.12, and I believe this will solve your issue.